# Pasar variable JavaScript a PHP de un Select

Tags: php, javascript, html-select

Tengo la siguiente cuestión.

Estoy trayendo los datos de un Select desde **JavaScript**.

```js
function lista() {
    var selected = document.getElementById("esp2");
    var selecte = selected.options[selected.selectedIndex].text;
    alert(selecte);
}
```

Con la variable `selecte` estoy guardando el valor para mandarlo a **PHP:**

```php
<?php
$PHPvariable = "<script>document.write(selecte)</script>";
echo "PHPvariable = ".$PHPvariable;
?>
```

Me está devolviendo el siguiente error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: selecte is not defined
```

Espero me puedan ayudar, Muchas Gracias.

Comment: Como llamas a esa funcion? Recuerda que PHP se ejecuta antes que JS

Comment: De esta manera la estoy llamando <select id="esp2" onChange="lista();">

Comment: Hola @JAIMEPOLANCO, la mejor forma de hacer es mediante una petición `Ajax`.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. puedes orientarme?, no se por donde empezar en AJAX.

Comment: @JAIMEPOLANCO, ¿Te sirve reproducir un ejemplo en JavaScript donde se realice una petición a PHP? Es decir, desde el lado del cliente (navegador) JavaScript haga una petición al servidor (que es el que tiene los script PHP). Me avisas para responderte con un ejemplo sencillo.

Comment: Si por favor seria de gran utilidad.

Comment: @JAIMEPOLANCO, dale. Ya te redacto una respuesta para que lo puedas reproducir.

Comment: Muchas Gracias.

Comment: @JAIMEPOLANCO, listo. Ya publiqué una respuesta con la explicación. Sin embargo, si observa alguna novedad me lo haces saber para actualizar la respuesta.

Comment: Ya logre tomar el valor pero al mandarlo a guardar en la variable en PHP me da error Warning: Undefined array key "seleccionar" y no me guarda la variable...

Comment: Hola @JAIMEPOLANCO. Voy a publicar un repositorio con las pruebas para que lo descargues. Lo voy a publicar en una actualización de la respuesta que te proporcioné.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Ejemplo PHP

### Enviar datos al servidor

Partiendo de un `select` :
Dada

```html
<select name="seleccionar" id="seleccionar">
    ...
</select>
```

Para capturar su valor con **JavaScript** podrías hacer lo siguiente:

```js
seleccionar.onchange = () => {
    console.log(seleccionar.value);
}
```

Es decir:

```js
seleccionar.onchange = () => {
  console.clear();

  console.log(seleccionar.value);
}
```

```html
<select id="seleccionar">
  <option value="">Seleccione un valor</option>
  <option value="valor1">Primer valor</option>
  <option value="valor2">Segundo valor</option>
  <option value="valor3">Tercer valor</option>
  <option value="valor4">Último valor</option>
</select>
```

Si embargo, para capturar el texto de la opción seleccionada y no su valor (bastante inusual) podrías plantearlo de esta manera:

```js
seleccionar.onchange = () => {
  console.clear();

  const elemento = document.querySelector( `[value="${seleccionar.value}"]` );

  console.log(elemento.textContent);
};
```

```html
<select name="seleccionar" id="seleccionar">
  <option value="">Seleccione un valor</option>
  <option value="valor1">Primer valor</option>
  <option value="valor2">Segundo valor</option>
  <option value="valor3">Tercer valor</option>
  <option value="valor4">Último valor</option>
</select>
```

Ahora bien, ya que tenemos claro esto, la pregunta es, ¿cómo pasar el valor de una variable **JavaScript** a **PHP**?

Se hace mediante una petición **Ajax**.

Por ejemplo, vamos a crear los fragmentos que siguen más abajo para reproducir el experimento.

Se tiene el siguiente fragmento HTML:

```html
<select name="seleccionar" id="seleccionar">
    <option value="">Seleccione un valor</option>
    <option value="valor1">Primer valor</option>
    <option value="valor2">Segundo valor</option>
    <option value="valor3">Tercer valor</option>
    <option value="valor4">Último valor</option>
</select>
```

Podrías definir en JavaScript lo que sigue:

```js
seleccionar.onchange = () => {
    let valor = seleccionar.value;
    let ruta = `archivo.php?seleccionar=${valor}`;

    // Enviamos nuestra petición al servidor 
    // con JavaScript:
    fetch(ruta)
        .then(respuesta => respuesta.text())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        })
};
```

En este caso, pasar el `valor` de un `select` como parámetro para que sea asignado a una variable `PHP` en el siguiente fragmento:

**archivo.php:**

```php
<?php
$variablePHP = $_GET['seleccionar'];
echo $variablePHP;
```

Donde `seleccionar` es el índice de **`$_GET`**.

### Pasar texto de la opción seleccionada

Para enviar el texto de la opción seleccionada se sigue el mismo procedimiento que en el caso anterior, pero, con una pequeña diferencia:

Se tiene el siguiente fragmento HTML:

```html
<select name="seleccionar" id="seleccionar">
    <option value="">Seleccione un valor</option>
    <option value="valor1">Primer valor</option>
    <option value="valor2">Segundo valor</option>
    <option value="valor3">Tercer valor</option>
    <option value="valor4">Último valor</option>
</select>
```

Podrías definir en JavaScript lo que sigue, pero con una diferencia:

```js
seleccionar.onchange = () => {
    console.clear();
    let texto = document.querySelector(`[value="${seleccionar.value}"]`).textContent;
    let ruta = `archivo.php?seleccionar=${texto}`;

    // Enviamos la petición a PHP con JavaScript:
    fetch(ruta)
        .then(respuesta => respuesta.text())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data);
        })
};
```

Y finalmente, sin cambios, nuestro archivo **PHP.**

**archivo.php:**

```php
<?php
$variablePHP = $_GET['seleccionar'];
echo $variablePHP;
```

Si desea profundizar sobre el uso de **fetch** podrías visitar la documentación oficial de **Mozilla:** [Uso de Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Utilizando_Fetch)

### Actualización

Dada la inquietud presentada en los comentarios dejé disponible en [**GitHub**](https://github.com/dlunamontilla/ejemploAjax) el código fuente para facilitar su implementación.

Ten en cuenta que para evitar un error similar al descrito en el comentario:

```
Undefined array key "seleccionar"
```

En la línea:

```php
$variablePHP = $_GET['seleccionar'];
```

Deberás validarlo primero y una forma de hacerlo es mediante una función (no es obligatorio, pero puede ser más elegante) que incluya un operador ternario:

```php
...
return ( $condicion ) ? "Verdadero" : "Falso";
```

Es decir, que nuestro código PHP completo quedaría así:

```php
<?php
function get( string $string ) {
    return ( isset($_GET[(string) $string]) )
        ? $_GET[(string) $string] : "";
}

$variablePHP = get("seleccionar");
echo $variablePHP;
```

De manera que, si `seleccionar` no existe devolverá una cadena vacía.

También se puede clonar directamente:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/dlunamontilla/ejemploAjax.git
```

Comment: Es una respuesta muy bien elaborada, se nota que te tomaste tu tiempo. +1

Comment: muchas gracias ya voy entendiendo un poco , lo puse en practica y me sale el siguiente error Warning: Undefined array key "seleccionar", la linea 2 que me da el error es: $variablePHP = $_GET['seleccionar'];

Comment: Gracias @Triby :)

Comment: Hola Jaime, ya hice una actualización en la que se deja disponible el ejemplo en el repositorio.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me funciono a la perfecion.                                                      una segunda pregunta y perdona por abusar de tu tiempo y conocimiento, quiero usar la variable que acabe de capturar $VariablePHP en mi documento principal, la inserto de ls siguiente forma pero no hace nada include("archivo.php");
 
$prueba = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM $tabla_db7 WHERE idgrupo1='$variablePHP'");

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. ademas quiero poder imprimir el resultado en un Input text

Comment: Hola @JAIMEPOLANCO, debes plantearla en otra pregunta.

Comment: @DavidE.LunaM. bueno gracias, ya la planteo

Comment: @JAIMEPOLANCO, recuerda aceptar la respuesta si te ayudó. Además, ganas dos puntos de reputación.